# Установка жёсткого диска на место DVD привода

Tags: железо

У меня ноутбук(данные напишу ниже), хочу поставить на место  DVD привода жёсткий диск с уже установленной Windows 7. Мой ноутбук: TOSHIBA Satellite A665 Version: PSAW3U-0DE039 Установленное ПО Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia, стоит SSD диск модель CT480BX500SSD1 (M6CR022). Диск с уже установленной Windows 7 который хочу поставить на место DVD привода-HDD Seagate.Прошу совета,как это выполнить.
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Понятия не имею, зачем в вопросе версии ОС и модель ссд, который уже установлен. Можно было бы модель устанавливаемого вместо привода диска указать, но скорее всего любой 2.5 подойдёт, а любой 3.5 - нет.

Comment: `Диск с уже установленной Windows 7` - Если винда устанавливалась на другом компьютере, то на твоём ноуте она не запустится.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Тогда наверное проще отформатировать этот диск и поставить пустым? Но как тогда в Linux разделить эти диски, чтобы потом именно на этот диск установить Windows 7, предварительно записав образ  Windows 7 на флешку?

Answer (score 3):

1. Выясняешь, какой формы у тебя дисковод.
2. На aliexpress пишешь запрос `ssd to dvd` и выбираешь подходящую штуковину типа этой за 220 руб:

   [image: фото]

PS: На самом деле даже не уверен, что первый шаг нужен, потому что что-то они все выглядят одинаково, но я бы проверил.

Comment: ага, и мне показалось что они одинаковые ) Ну по идеи сидиромы имеют один одинаковый формат )

Comment: @Crus, ну внутри-то да, в вот снаружи и особенно крепления к корпусу и плате - кто ж их знает. Так что сначала проверить лишним не будет, особенно с учётом небыстрой доставки.

Comment: Обычно отличается только пластиковая накладка снаружи, на али идут комплекты стандартный переходник+накладка под модель ноута

Answer (score 1):

Это немного не то сообщество - тут скорее по вопросам разработки, чем железу :)

По делу - https://hddcaddy.eu/toshiba-satellite-a665-hdd-caddy/
Вам нужно взять подходящий переходник, который вставляется вместо сидирома, а в него вставляется винчестер.

Comment: Ого у них цены - 24 евро за железку. Впрочем, судя по видео у них лоток металлический, но есть ли в этом смысл? Ну и действительно ли этот кусок металла стоит в 10 раз дороже пластика?

Comment: Наверняка достаточно обычного с алиэкспрессу, угу ) По ссылке ценность скорее в видео для общего понимания что это такое все же. Ну, кстати, и модель прям под этот ноут.. вроде )

Comment: Ну если под конкретную модель, то это плюс. Ну и быстрая доставка (а она быстрая?) потенциально тоже плюс. Но когда разница в 10 раз, то как-то повод задуматься, а не купить ли на разницу в цене графический планшет, например)))

Comment: Согласен ) Я дернул ссылки из инета как пример того, что нужно. )